# Customsearch API - Billing

Tags: google-custom-search

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) link, it says that ***JSON Custom Search API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day.***

I have been using the **JSON Customsearch API** which is `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1` for quite a while now. Yesterday, I fired around 360 requests. So does it mean that since I crossed 100 search queries, I'll be charged for it?

The reason that I asked this was because my Dashboard doesn't show any charges yet.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to pay it. 
According to my experience, the charge information on Dashboard do not refresh all the time.

Comment: Also, it says `$5 per 1000 queries` is this like on a per day basis? I mean, how are those 1000 queries counted? 1000/day?

Comment: It means that you have to pay for ((your queries - 100) mod 1000) * 5 USD/ per day